# Caldroid Dialog and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, caldroid

I'm building an app in which I need a calendar so the user can pick a date. 
I'm trying to embed the Caldroid library in my project and I want to show the calendar not in a new `Activity`, but in a `Dialog` instead.

My questions are:

1. Since I'm using an `Activity` which already has some widgets, do I need to change it to `FragmentActivity`?
2. I want to show the Caldroid `Dialog` by pressing a calendar `ImageButton`, do I need a second `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight to your questions:

A) Caldroid from what I can see is just another fragment, therefore there is **no need** of changing your `Activity` to `FragmentActivity` check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) (any `ViewGroup` can hold a fragment.

B) Let me see if I get this: You want on the click of an ImageButton that is located on **your** activity to show the Caldroid's calendar dialog? If that is the case then you **don't need to** do anything more than override the onClick() method of the `ImageButton` and implement it to launch Caldroid. No need to have a second fragment activity.

Comment: Thank you! I followed the steps, added the project and set the listener but there is a `FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` which causes an error. Also `R.id.calendar1` does not exist. Should I create it?

Comment: Did you integrate the library with your application exactly as https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid#setup instructs? Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I added `compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:1.1.8'` to my gradle build file.

Comment: What is the error you get from `FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`? post your stacktrace

Comment: I figured it out. It was simple but I new here. I opened the example and copy and paste the parts I needed. It's very straight forward. But instead of `t.replace` i used `t.attach`